# Linux: outbound IP to my subnet do not appear in tcpdump and do not appear to be sent

Tags: linux, ip, firewall, ping, arp

I'm trying to setup a poorly designed Wi-Fi device and I've connected to its wifi network and set my IP and routes manually as DHCP does not appear to be working.

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.10.100 dev wlp2s0b1 src 192.168.10.3
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlp2s0b1 scope link
```

When I try to `ping 192.168.10.100` (the alleged default IP), the `ping` utility shows no output. `tcpdump` also shows nothing, though there is activity on the network, and ARP happens occasionally:

```
17:12:43.147305 ARP, Request who-has gateway tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
17:12:43.148516 ARP, Reply gateway is-at d8:eb:97:a2:3b:fc (oui Unknown), length 28


17:14:15.914295 IP localhost.localdomain.50800 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 171
17:14:15.921169 IP gateway.ssdp > localhost.localdomain.50800: UDP, length 279
17:14:17.750750 ARP, Request who-has localhost.localdomain tell gateway, length 28
17:14:17.750799 ARP, Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 70:18:8b:06:ba:57 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

Additionally, if I send pings to a host outside of the subnet, `tcpdump -i wlp2s0b1` shows the following (not in this order, just that it shows the request and response):

```
17:13:16.989280 IP gateway > localhost.localdomain: ICMP net 192.168.1.1 unreachable, length 92
17:13:17.989237 IP localhost.localdomain > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 27888, seq 12, length 64
```

even though ping shows no output. (?)

How is this behavior possible? What's happening?

Here's my firewall:

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Dec 19 17:19:43 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [29:6414]
:INPUT ACCEPT [23:5137]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10380:773373]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9239:678321]
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --sport 1500 -j SNAT --to-source :30000
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --sport 1504 -j SNAT --to-source :30001
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 19 17:19:43 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Dec 19 17:19:43 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [52617:8798972]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [54107:7942732]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 19 17:19:43 2017
```

Also, `tcpdump -i lo` does not show any of the packets I'm looking for

EDIT
Some updates:

```
# ip route get 192.168.10.100
192.168.10.100 dev wlp2s0b1 src 192.168.10.3 uid 0 
    cache 

# ip addr show wlp2s0b1
3: wlp2s0b1:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:18:8b:--:--:-- brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.3/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global wlp2s0b1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ff1e:167e:8d67:797d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also, looking at `tcpdump -n`, 192.168.10.100 is indeed 'gateway', not sure how that name is getting in there.

**UPDATE** sorry guys, it is because I was running an IPsec client with local selector containing `192.168.10.0/24`. I did not see evidence of this using the `ip` utility, including with `ip route show table all`  but stopping the client released this 'blackhole'. Thanks

Comment: Aren't you missing the -i option before the interface name? Man doesn't show that syntax as valid...

Comment: Check `ip addr` to make sure the addresses and netmasks are correct. Also, do a `tcpdump -n -i wlp2s0b1` to see the numeric addresses, so you can check if they are correct (I assume `gateway` = 192.168.10.100, but who knows...). Try `ip route get 192.168.10.100` to make sure you don't have funny policy routing rules for some reason.

Comment: Are we looking at network configuration on the WiFi device, or on a client of that WiFi device?

Comment: What's your network topology, and which part is wired and which part wireless? What is the IP address for the host called "gateway"?

Comment: @Zip sorry, meant to indicate it with the -i option, will correct.

Comment: @roaima, it is a client of the wifi switch/router (which is a commodity/blackbox device). I'll check what 'gateway is'. The topology consists of the client with a single 'wireless medium' connected to the gateway and no other devices

Comment: Please add that ^^ to your question where it's easy for everyone to read.

Comment: Your IPsec comment... Is that the solution? Because if so it belongs as an Answer. Or else you may want to delete this question